# Spring Batch - How to calculate parameters at launch time?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

My batches are launched within Tomcat. The readers/processors/writers are initialized at startup (prototype beans) but I need them to compute parameters at launch time not at startup time.

How can I make the parameters used in the batch computed at launch time ? 
I am using a batch which makes a calculation depending on the system date. (for example an OffsetDateTime.now() parameter).

Will this use case be taken in consideration in the future releases?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is this a question? Or a feature request? The later should be posted on the projects issue tracker, not SO.